# I am trying to pass object property in console.log but output says undefined

Tags: javascript, object

```
name = {
  first: "kyle",
  last: "Simpson",
  age: 39,
};

console.log(`My name is ${ name.first}`);
```

Comment: Try a different name for the variable other than `name`, or [declare it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements#Declarations) within a function. The script may just be colliding with a [predefined global that can only be a string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name).

Comment: avoid variable named `name` in global scope - browsers make that variable essentially read only

Answer (score 3):

You should not use [`name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name) as your variable as it is a property of global [Window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) object.

You can still use `name` (but not recommended) by declaring that with `let` as this will ***create a block scope local variable***.

```js
let name = { first: "kyle", last: "Simpson", age: 39, };

console.log(`My name is ${ name.first }`);
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the reserved word `name` for js variable.
Can you try the below code

```html
<script>
    
    var names = {
      first: "kyle",
      last: "Simpson",
      age: "39"
    };
    
    console.log("My name is "+names.first);


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not declared the variable with any identifier like var, let or const, it will look for window.name which you cannot use. Hence like @Ajith mentioned, use var or let to declare it first.

```
    // You can also use let
    var name = {
      first: "kyle",
      last: "Simpson",
      age: 39,
    };

    console.log(`My name is ${ name.first}`);
```

Comment: Thank you tuna for your answer !
but i used var name ...... it is showing same output